# How can I find a node of a particular type in Neo4j Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to find a node which has a property type = user in Neo4j, but not all of my nodes have the type property. When I do this:

```
START root=node(*) where root.type="user" RETURN root
```

I get the error:

Cypher error

```
The property 'type' does not exist on Node[0]
```

: how can I get this to work, or am I misunderstanding something fundamental with Neo4j?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `has()` function. The Node (Node[0]) with id 0 is called the reference node in Neo4j which is used by Neo4j internally.

```
START root=node(*) where has(root.type) AND root.type="user" RETURN root
```